# Error with React Native Colour Picker module

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Please Help!!!

I Copy pasted code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-color-picker
In my App.js file but its not running

I installed on 3 library mentioned but it didn't work

Please help me to fix this code or I need a code of similar Colour wheel

(There is module Colour wheel similar to Colourpicker but it also didn't work for me)

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

import ColorPicker from 'react-native-wheel-color-picker'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[]}>
                <ColorPicker
                    ref={r => { this.picker = r }}
                    color={this.state.currentColor}
                    swatchesOnly={this.state.swatchesOnly}
                    onColorChange={this.onColorChange}
                    onColorChangeComplete={this.onColorChangeComplete}
                    thumbSize={40}
                    sliderSize={40}
                    noSnap={true}
                    row={false}
                    swatchesLast={this.state.swatchesLast}
                    swatches={this.state.swatchesEnabled}
                    discrete={this.state.disc}
                />
                <SomeButton onPress={() => this.picker.revert()} />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

export default App
[Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPnJy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error says `null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.currentColor')`

The `color` prop on the ColorPicker component expects an object and is given null. This is because there is no state set. Using a class based component you can set the state in the constructor. This gets rid of the error. If you want you can define you "start" color in the state `currentColor: "#cc7"`

```js
import { Component } from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";

import ColorPicker from "react-native-wheel-color-picker";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[]}>
        <ColorPicker
          ref={(r) => {
            this.picker = r;
          }}
          color={this.state.currentColor}
          swatchesOnly={this.state.swatchesOnly}
          onColorChange={this.onColorChange}
          onColorChangeComplete={this.onColorChangeComplete}
          thumbSize={40}
          sliderSize={40}
          noSnap={true}
          row={false}
          swatchesLast={this.state.swatchesLast}
          swatches={this.state.swatchesEnabled}
          discrete={this.state.disc}
        />
        // SomeButton
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

PS: the `SomeButton` component will also throw an error since it is not defined.